# Runnable Jar file not detecting TestNG Classpath

Tags: java, jar, testng, executable-jar

I am trying to create a runnable jar file that has some TestNG tests.I can run the project files from Eclipse but when I create a jar file it can't find the required library. A possible classpath issue I guess.There are similar questions on the forum but none of them have any answers that could help me resolve this issue. When I run the jar file id gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG
            at test.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:11)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            ... 1 more
```

This is my Class with the main method.

```
package test;

import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestRunner {
    
    static TestNG testNG;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestClasses( new Class[] {App1.class});
        testNG.run();
        }
}
```

Then there is a class that has some very simple tests.Everything runs fine from eclipse but the jar file has the problem. The problem seems very simple but yet I have not been able to resolve it. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: How are you running the compiled JAR?

Comment: java -jar test.jar

Comment: You might want to assemble a JAR file containing all classes required at runtime (making an "uber"-jar), otherwise you have to specify the classpath locations using the `-cp` switch (applies to both directories and ZIP-containers).